# getText is not working for an element with Tagname as h2

Tags: selenium, gettext

I am trying to read text of an element from tag Name h2 and i am getting null value returned.

```
<div id="informationModal" class="modal fade in" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block; padding-right: 16px;">
        <div class="modal-md modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1 class="modal-title">Message</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h2 style="font-size:17px;">
                        Request cannot be processed. Access denied, read only.
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="cancelinformation" class="btn-cancelconfirm btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried getText

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='informationModal']//h2")
WebElement certMessage;
String message = certMessage.getText();
System.out.println("Message -->"+ message);
```

Expected Result --> Request cannot be processed. Access denied, read only.

Actual Result --> []

Comment: please read [mcve] and edit your question accordingly, what error stack trace you getting? where is your code trials? how the element html structure looks like? etc .. things required to reproduce/debug the problem, from henceforth remember to add the necessary details in order to get possible helpful responses

Comment: Seems to be a _modal dialog box_, you need to induce _WebDriverWait_.

Comment: Awesome thanks it worked